# How to send cookies with file_get_contents

Tags: php, session, cookies, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get the contents from another file with `file_get_contents` (don't ask why).
I have two files: *test1.php* and *test2.php*. *test1.php* returns a string, bases on the user that is logged in.

*test2.php* tries to get the contents of *test1.php* and is being executed by the browser, thus getting the cookies.

To send the cookies with `file_get_contents`, I create a streaming context:

```
$opts = array('http' => array('header'=> 'Cookie: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']."\r\n"))`;
```

I'm retrieving the contents with:

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/test1.php", false, $opts);
```

But now I get the error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.example.com/test1.php) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Does somebody knows what I'm doing wrong here?

edit:
forgot to mention: Without the *streaming_context*, the page just loads. But without the cookies I don't get the info I need.

Comment: FYI- if you are using A2hosting you have to request fopen access to be granted (they shut it down by default for security reasons)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First, this is probably just a typo in your question, but the third arguments to file_get_contents() needs to be your streaming context, NOT the array of options.  I ran a quick test with something like this, and everything worked as expected

```
$opts = array('http' => array('header'=> 'Cookie: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']."\r\n"));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$contents = file_get_contents('http://example.com/test1.txt', false, $context);
echo $contents;
```

The error indicates the server is returning a 404. Try fetching the URL **from the machine PHP is running on** and **not** from your workstation/desktop/laptop.  It may be that your web server is having trouble reaching the site, your local machine has a cached copy, or some other network screwiness.

Be sure you repeat your exact request when running this test, including the cookie you're sending (command line curl is good for this).  It's entirely possible that the page in question may load fine in a browser without the cookie, but when you send the cookie the site actually is returning a 404.

Make sure that $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'] has the raw cookie you think it does.

If you're screen scraping, download Firefox and a copy of the LiveHTTPHeaders extension.  Perform all the necessary steps to reach whatever page it is you want in Firefox.  Then, using the output from LiveHTTPHeaders, recreate the exact same request requence.  Include every header, **not** just the cookies.

Finally, [PHP Curl](http://us.php.net/curl) exists for a reason.  If at all possible, (I'm not asking!) use it instead. :)

Comment: While using this code I am getting an error of "HTML header fail", so I need to get solution by adding "session_write_close();" before file_get_contents. Is this proper way?

Answer (score 16):

Just to share this information.
When using `session_start()`, the session file is lock by PHP. Thus the actual script is the only script that can access the session file. If you try to access it via `fsockopen()` or `file_get_contents()` you can wait a long time since you try to open a file that has been locked.

One way to solve this problem is to use the `session_write_close()` to unlock the file and relock it after with `session_start()`.

Example:

```
<?php
 $opts = array('http' => array('header'=> 'Cookie: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']."\r\n"));
 $context = stream_context_create($opts);
 session_write_close(); // unlock the file
 $contents = file_get_contents('http://120.0.0.1/controler.php?c=test_session', false, $context);
 session_start(); // Lock the file
 echo $contents;
?>
```

Since `file_get_contents()` is a blocking function, both script won't be in concurrency while trying to modify the session file.

But i'm sure this is not the best manner to manipulate session with an extend connection.

Btw: it's faster than **cURL** and `fsockopen()`

Let me know if you find something better.

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this :) I wish I could give more upvotes because you just saved me from pulling all of my hair out.

Comment: Thanks, it's a pleasure for me to share ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, are you attempting `file_get_contents` on a page that has a space in it?  I remember trying to use fgc on a URL that had a space in the name and while my web browser parsed it just fine, fgc didn't.  I ended up having to use a `str_replace` to replace ' ' with '%20'.

I would think that this should have been relatively easy to spot that though as it would report only half of the filename.  Also, I noticed in one of these posts, someone used \r\n  while defining the headers.  Keep in mind that PHP doesn't like these to be in single quotes, but they work fine in double.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that file1.php exists on the server. Try opening it in your own browser to make sure!