# accessing $_SESSION when using file_get_contents in PHP

Tags: php, session, file-get-contents

I have a page called send.email.php which sends an email - pretty simple stuff - I pass an order id, it creates job request and sends it out.  This works fine when used in the context I developed it (Use javascript to make an AJAX call to the URL and pass the order_id as a query parameter)

I am now trying to reuse the exact same page in another application however I am calling it using php `file_get_contents($base_url.'admin/send.email.php?order_id='.$order_id)`.  When I call the page this way, the $_SESSION array is empty `isempty()` = 1.

Is this because I am initiating a new session using `file_get_contents` and the values I stored in the $_SESSION on login are not available to me within there?

-->
Thanks for the feedback. It makes sense that the new call doesn't have access to the existing session...

New problem though:

I now get: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! When trying to execute:

```
$opts = array('http' => array('header'=> 'Cookie: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']."\r\n"));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$contents = file_get_contents($base_url.'admin/send.sms.php?order_id='.order_id, false, $context);
```

YET, the URL works fine if I call it as: (It just doesn't let me access session)

```
$result file_get_contents($base_url.'admin/send.sms.php?order_id='.$order_id);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is because the server uses cookies to track clients. When you call the page from your browser the session cookie is passed along the request. When you use `file_get_contents` function, no cookie is passed and the server cannot identify the client. [Here's a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306591/problem-with-sending-cookies-with-file-get-contents) that might help you.