# Get the source of a file using PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get the source of a file using PHP and the file_get_contents function.

The problem is that the website requires a login. I thought that this could be bypassed by logging into the site first and then use the file_get_contents function but this is not the case. The page that the function returns is the login page.

This is the code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['getroster'])){
$file = stripslashes(file_get_contents('https://intranet.hlf.de/custom/cddTUB.asp?show=1'));
print ($file);
}

?>
```

As you can see when running this function, or when going to the url, it requests a username, password and company from a dropdown list.

Is it possible to pass these values to the page by using this or any other PHP function. Or maybe doing it in a totally different way?

Answer (score 2):

The cookies in your browser, and the cookies can be sent with PHP are completely unrelated.

Using [curl](http://php.net/curl) you can set the options `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` to specify a file in which cookies should be stored and loaded from.

Doing that you will first have to make a request that does the login (this will get you the cookie). Next you can do the request you wanted to do as a logged in user (because now curl has the cookies).

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the correct cookies.  If you can use curl, then the script on [this page](http://www.knowledgesutra.com/forums/topic/38162-automatic-login-using-curl/) should help.  You can also take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306591/problem-with-sending-cookies-with-file-get-contents) (it's slightly different from your case since it's reusing browser cookies to make the request).

Answer (score 0):

Any change you could post an example of how to do that Daniel?

There wouldn't be an option of creating a login like form which sents the user information to the page to login automatically?
Read something about the stream_context_create function which could do a login by sending header information but I really wouldn't where to start. The examples posted about that only give username and password but I ofcourse have a third option to post to the authentication page!