# file_get_contents drops values from database, if id is variable

Tags: php, sql, file-get-contents

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM data where data.id=".$myrow[0]."";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

$homepage = file_get_contents('my page'); 
echo $homepage;
```

Page 'my page' contains $rows[1].

If *$query="SELECT * FROM data where data.id=1"* then $homepage displays $rows[1].

But if *$query="SELECT * FROM data where data.id=".$myrow[0].""* then $homepage displays empty instead of $rows[1].

$myrow[0] was received correctly, in this case it is 2. Converting to the int didn't help.

Comment: Could you show dump of $myrow?

Comment: @BerianidzeLuka $myrow[0] is string(1) "2", $myrow array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(6) "steven" [2]=> string(6) "steven" }

Comment: Try it like $query = "SELECT * FROM data where data.id='".$myrow[0]."'";

Comment: @Berianidze Luka thank you for help, but didn't help. I understood after file_get_contents dump of $myrow becames the NULL.

Comment: What is my page here file_get_contents('my page');  ? Please, show the code you are actually using

Comment: @Berianidze Luka 'my page' contain <?php
session_start();
include_once 'custom-data.php'; /*file with database requestes (code in my Question)*/
echo "<b>Test</b>".$rows[1];
?>

Comment: @Berianidze Luka thank you very much for your help, my ussue was like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306591/not-able-to-send-cookies-with-file-get-contents. There is I have found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myrow[0] = 1; // add this line and try
$query = "SELECT * FROM data where data.id=".$myrow[0];
// ...
```

If it works, check if you have data with the id being 2.
If you have data, try

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM data where data.id=" . intval($myrow[0]);
```

Comment: thanks for help, but the issue is after file-get-contents var_dump(intval($myrow[0])) becomes from int(2) to int(0), var_dump($myrow[0]) becomes the NULL.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, my ussue was like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306591/not-able-to-send-cookies-with-file-get-contents. There is I have found a solution.